# Cannot get is_front_page to work in Wordpress footer

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, conditional-statements

I have a few lines of code in my footer.php file that I only want activated on the site's home page. I have tried various suggestions for using is_front_page that I have found online, but none of them have worked. I am obviously not a php expert!

[This is the site](http://stage.youth-spark.org), and I am using a static page as the home page. Below is the code I'd like activated only on the home page. All help is appreciated!

```
<?php   
$display_brands_widget = false;
if (isset($qode_options_flat['footer_brands_area'])){
    if ($qode_options_flat['footer_brands_area'] == "yes")  $display_brands_widget = true;
}
if($display_brands_widget): ?> 
    <div class="carousel_slider_holder clearfix">
        <ul class="carousel_slider">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'brands' ); ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to some great diagnostic help from @chris-rogers, I was able to figure out that is_front_page "wasn't working" in footer content because I was using loading pages through Ajax. The simple solution ended up being to move the snippet of code in question to a new page template, so that it only loaded when that page content was called.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [is_home()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home)?

Comment: I have, but no luck. I can't even get is_front_page, is_home, or is_page to work in printing out a simple line of html. I'm not sure if it's a problem with my theme, or if my code is wrong.

Comment: Try **echo get_the_ID();** and tell me if that matches the ID of your pages (you can find that out by clicking on the page from the Worpdress admin and looking at the ID in the URL). You may be referencing this outside [the loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) which means you cannot access the post information.

Comment: Ah...I think you've found the problem! So, get_the_ID() confirms for me the page ID I was using for the home page is correct, but then when I load any other page, it still says the page ID is the home page. The problem seems to be that I'm using Ajax to load pages, because when I go directly to any other non-home page (instead of using links from the home page), the page ID is correct.

Comment: So now I have it working using is_page(), but Ajax is preventing it from working when I navigate using internal links. Do you know a way around this? I really would prefer not to lose Ajax for the site. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Okay, so you're using AJAX to load every page, and the container page is you front page. I think I follow you. Okay so whatever call to action (CTA) you are using to load the page, surely you have an ID or slug of some sort? If so then you could do [something like this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/get-page-or-post-id-from-javascript) to return the ID of the page and assign it to a variable for use that way? Let me know

Comment: .. Sorry, Let me know if this fixes it, if so I will edit my answer for others who may have a similar issue can find an answer. If not then can you post a code snippet so I can help. Cheers

Comment: Thanks Chris. I tried following the example you posted but had no luck. I really don't think I have the programming skills to pull it off. I think that the slug might be a good way to handle. I only want the snippet of code to be active on the home page (for which the slug would be /Home/  if I didn't have that page set as the front page). Not sure if this gives you enough info to suggest anything, but anything you recommend, I'll try and then post the results!

Comment: Thanks to your help, I ended up figuring out a simpler way to get the job done. I just created a new template for the home page, and added the php to the bottom of that template (and removed it from the footer). Couldn't have gotten there without your help. Thank you so much!